# dynamically iterate xsl value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following `xsl` code.

```
<xsl:for-each select="value">   
<xsl:if test="../@field_value=@value">
<input type="radio" id="{$fname}{position()}" name="{$fname}" value="{@value}" /><xsl:value-of select="@value"/><br/>                                       
</xsl:if>                       
</xsl:for-each>
```

What I want is to show dynamic no of radio buttons with values. There are three values, so the for loop is running for three times. Also it is printing three times the last value.
E.g. the three values are:

- The code
- The alfa code
- The numeric code

Each time I run the code, three radio buttons with text **The numeric Code** are shown. How can I show the three different values with three radio buttons?

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Could you please add the input XML, the expected output, and the complete XSLT, and try to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a condition for radio button, and put for each loop for options of radio button
your xml:

```
<fieldtype>radio</fieldtype>
<name>CODE<name>
<option>The code</option>
<option>The alfa code</option>
<option>The numeric code</option>
```

now in your XSLT ,you can provide for each loop for `<option>` tag with the input type radio, when it encounters radio as field type

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the issue?